# "Java EE Build settings" tab missing in IntelliJ Idea 12?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, intellij-idea, build-settings

I'm relatively new to Java and to IntelliJ Idea in particular (trying it out as a part of students license for the university). I've been following this guide: http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Creating_JavaEE_Applications_and_Servlets_with_IntelliJ_IDEA on creating servlets; the problem is at the step "Creating Servlet" I cannot find the "Java EE Build settings" tab in the Web facet properties window, as shown in the screenshot.

In my case, the layout is similar to what should be in the "Web settings" tab of the same window, it seems, but the "Java EE Build settings" is missing. I realize that this guide was written for an older version of Idea, so things might have changed since then, but I had no luck finding the place in the settings which is now serving the same purpose (and a multitude of screenshots of Idea of different versions running on different OSes, all having this "Java EE Build settings" tab, confuses me). Where is the replacement for that tab in version 12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial you are using is for IntelliJ 7.0

Here are two for IntelliJ 12.0:

- [Creating a simple Web application for Tomcat in IntelliJ IDEA 12](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Creating_a_simple_Web_application_for_Tomcat_in_IntelliJ_IDEA_12)
- [Developing and running a Java EE Hello World application](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Creating_a_simple_Web_application_for_Tomcat_in_IntelliJ_IDEA_12)